# Prevent Refresh on anchor tag Click

Tags: asp.net, url, anchor, c#-3.0

i want load the page using anchor tag like this go                        from any content page. i want to prevent page refresh on anchor tag Click but at same time it should load Different page. example below here is content page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <a href="WebForm2.aspx">go</a>
</asp:Content>
```

and on master Page

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Use `LinkButton` and load content page from withing onclick of it

Comment: nothing happened @Imad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below will not work on server side Controls, also you need to change all content pages into individual.

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        if (page!='#') {
            window.history.pushState("string", "Title", page);
            $("#divid").load(page, function () {
                //write your stuff
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault(); 
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a class="link1" href="WebForm2.aspx">go</a>


<script>
$(function(){
    $("a.link1").click(function()
    {
         $.get("WebForm2.aspx" );
         return false; // prevent default browser refresh on "#" link
    });
});
</script>
```